# Problem when COPY INTO TABLE is performed with special characters into the files

Tags: utf-8, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a file with a column data something like this. As can be seen there is a special character in between.

The original datatype was varchar(60). When COPY INTO TABLE is performed then it is throwing an error. I change the collation to utf-8 and still doing the same. Is there a way to solve this problem?

ABC COMPANY ▒ Sample Data

Thanks!

Comment: can you share the problematic file?

Comment: It just has one column. ABC COMPANY ▒ Sample Data

Comment: create or replace table t4 (i varbinary(100) );

Comment: The table is a basic one and nothing fancy.

Comment: yes, but I don't know how the file is encoded - if I just copy paste from Stack Overflow, I might not be able to solve and fix the same problem that you are finding

Comment: what error it is throwing ? i can copy the data

Comment: Please update your question with the complete COPY INTO statement as well as the file format you are using. Thanks